# Running a code generator during an IntelliJ Plugin build

Tags: java, build, intellij-idea, code-generation, intellij-plugin

I'm working on a project that's distributed as an IntelliJ plugin. Some of the required sources for the project are created by a code generation step prior to compiling the Java source files. These generated files are not placed in source control.

I have Ant tasks and a Maven plugin for this code generator that reliably integrates the code generation step into either of those two build systems.

How does IntelliJ support code generation during the build process for an IntelliJ Plugin project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ plugin deployment supports code generation indirectly :)

Each time your run Build > Prepare Plugin Module  For Deployment, IntelliJ invokes "Make" command.

What you need to do is to mark Ant or Maven task as "Execute Before Make", then each time you run Make or Prepare Plugin For Deployment, the selected task will be executed.

[image]

> > How can I run the generate-sources phase? I don't see a way to include new phases under Lifecycle.

Your plugin should have `generate-sources` goal.

Sample POM

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipser</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.modello</groupId>
                <artifactId>modello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <models>
                                <model>src/main/mdo/maven.mdo</model>
                            </models>
                            <version>4.0.0</version>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: How can I run the `generate-sources` phase? I don't see a way to include new phases under **Lifecycle**.

Comment: Your plugin supposed to have `generate-sources` goal.